# Анимация слайдера в next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scss, nextjs, слайдер

Есть массив объектов с данными (изображение, название), на экране я отображаю 3 карточки. С помощью `slice()` вырезаю их из общего массива.

При нажатии на стрелку вперед или назад, меняется индекс и соответственно отображается следующая карточка. Но проблема такая: я не понимаю, как сделать анимацию плавную, так как тут меняется не посредством `transform`, а просто индексом. Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
const newsWeek = [
    {
        image: '/allFiles/images-mebel/main-page/04-fourth-block/firstImg.jpg',
        name: 'firstImg',
        alt: 'firstImg',
    },
    {
        image: '/allFiles/images-mebel/main-page/04-fourth-block/secondImg.jpg',
        name: 'secondImg',
        alt: 'firstImg',
    },
    {
        image: '/allFiles/images-mebel/main-page/04-fourth-block/thirdImg.jpg',
        name: 'thirdImg',
        alt: 'firstImg',
    },
    {
        image: '/allFiles/images-mebel/main-page/04-fourth-block/firstImg.jpg',
        name: 'fourthtImg',
        alt: 'firstImg',
    },
    {
        image: '/allFiles/images-mebel/main-page/04-fourth-block/firstImg.jpg',
        name: 'fifthImg',
        alt: 'firstImg',
    },
    {
        image: '/allFiles/images-mebel/main-page/04-fourth-block/firstImg.jpg',
        name: 'sixthImg',
        alt: 'firstImg',
    },
];
```

```js
'use client';

import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './cards.module.scss';
import ArrowLeft from './arrowLeft/ArrowLeft';
import ArrowRight from './arrowRight/ArrowRight';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Cards = ({ newsWeek }) => {
    let [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const visibleCards = 3; // Количество видимых карточек

    const setCurrentIndexMinus = async () => {
        currentIndex === 0
            ? setCurrentIndex(newsWeek.length - 3)
            : setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
    };

    const setCurrentIndexPlus = async () => {
        currentIndex === newsWeek.length - 3
            ? setCurrentIndex(0)
            : setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
    };

    console.log(newsWeek.length);

    const chooseClass = (index) => {
        if (index === visibleCards - 3) {
            return styles.prevCard;
        }
        if (index === visibleCards - 2) {
            return styles.mainCard;
        }
        if (index === visibleCards - 1) {
            return styles.nextCard;
        }
    };

    const chooseWidth = (index) => {
        if (index === visibleCards - 2) {
            return 565;
        } else {
            return 367;
        }
    };

    const chooseHeight = (index) => {
        if (index === visibleCards - 2) {
            return 326;
        } else {
            return 262;
        }
    };

    const borderRadius = (index) => {
        if (index !== visibleCards - 2) {
            return '20px';
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.allCards}>
            {newsWeek
                .slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + visibleCards)
                .map((news, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className={chooseClass(index)} key={index}>
                            <Image
                                src={news.image}
                                width={chooseWidth(index)}
                                height={chooseHeight(index)}
                                alt="image"
                                className={styles.image}
                                style={{
                                    height: chooseHeight(index),
                                    borderRadius: borderRadius(index),
                                }}
                            />
                            {index === visibleCards - 2 && (
                                <div className={styles.underImg}>
                                    <h3 className={styles.cardTitle}>
                                        {news.name}
                                    </h3>
                                    <button className={styles.cardButton}>
                                        ПОКАЗАТЬ
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}

            <ArrowLeft setCurrentIndexleft={setCurrentIndexMinus} />

            <ArrowRight setCurrentIndexRight={setCurrentIndexPlus} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cards;



'use client';
import Image from 'next/image';
import arrowRight from '../../../../../../public/allFiles/images-mebel/AllSiteImg/arrowRight.svg';
import styles from './arrowRight.module.scss';

const ArrowRight = ({ setCurrentIndexRight }) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        setCurrentIndexRight();
    };

    return (
        <button className={styles.arrowRight} onClick={handleClick}>
            <Image src={arrowRight} width={50} height={50} alt="arrow right" />
        </button>
    );
};

export default ArrowRight;


'use client';
import Image from 'next/image';
import arrowLeft from '../../../../../../public/allFiles/images-mebel/AllSiteImg/arrowLeft.svg';
import styles from './arrowLeft.module.scss';

const ArrowLeft = ({ setCurrentIndexleft }) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        setCurrentIndexleft();
    };

    return (
        <button className={styles.arrowLeft} onClick={handleClick}>
            <Image src={arrowLeft} width={50} height={50} alt="arrow left" />
        </button>
    );
};

export default ArrowLeft;
```

```css
@import '../../../../styles/verriable.scss';

.cards {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.allCards {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;

    transition: 1s ease;
}

.underImg {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

    background-color: #fff;

    width: 565px;
    height: 100px;

    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    margin: 0 auto;

    padding: 0 80px;
}

.cardTitle {
    font-family: $font-main;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cardButton {
    display: block;

    color: #fff;
    font-family: $font-main;
    font-size: 1.25rem;

    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #a9bfd4;

    width: 161px;
    height: 42px;

    margin: auto 0;
}

.cards {
    position: relative;
}

.mainCard {
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nextCard,
.prevCard,
.nextImage,
.prevImage {
    position: absolute;
}

.nextCard::after,
.prevCard::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    border-radius: 20px;

    z-index: 11;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.prevCard {
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;

    transition: 1s ease;
}

.nextCard {
    top: 50%;
    right: -6.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;

    transition: 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам решил вопрос, если кому-то поможет в будущем, увеличил кол-во отображаемых карточек до 5 и вместо изменения индексом, меняю по средством transform